# Updating text in tkinter with a button using a random list

Tags: python, tkinter

Im trying to make a random name generator using an imported list and tkinter. I can get a random name its just that it doesn't change the name when the Generate new name button is pressed. Also im new to python, so anything helps lol. Edit: I fixed it by updating name1 everytime instead of calling the name1 function.

Thoughts?

```
import random
from namelist import namel1ist
import tkinter as tk

name1 = (random.choice(namel1ist) + " " + random.choice(namel1ist))

print(name1)

root = tk.Tk()
tk.Button(root, text='Generate new name',command=name1).pack()
w = tk.Label(root, text=name1)
w.pack()

tk.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the command as its own function, that changes the text value of the label.
At the moment you only call `random.choice(namel1ist)` once, when the label is created. Like this the text will be set.

Comment: Idk if this was the right way to go about it but i tried it like this '' ' import random
from namelist import namel1ist
import tkinter as tk


def namecall():
    random.choice(namel1ist)


root = tk.Tk()
tk.Button(root, text='Generate new name', command=namecall).pack()
w = tk.Label(root, text=namecall)
w.pack()

tk.mainloop()
' and this is what the window looked like https://ibb.co/d4sPm62

Comment: unfortunately the image doesn't show for me

Answer (score 2):

frankly i dont know what the `namelist` module does, but heres a working example that you can work around with:

```
import random
import tkinter as tk

names = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l',
             'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

def random_name():
    name = random.choice(names) + " " + random.choice(names)
    w.config(text=name)
    return name


root = tk.Tk()
random_button = tk.Button(root, text='Generate new name', command=random_name)
random_button.pack()

w = tk.Label(root, text=(random.choice(names) +" " + random.choice(names)))
w.pack()

tk.mainloop()
```